# fav icon and style not appearing on live website

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i have created a website and hosted it on ionos hosting service, my website is live now. My home page is index.php. i tried editing the home page of website like the following:

i added a fav icon like this:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img\website logo.png">
```

and i also did some styling in one of the image in the home page to make its width big like following:

```html
<div>
      <img src="img/competebig_logocolor.png" style="width:300px;" alt="logo" class="responsive img-main">
</div>
```

the changes i did is showing in my local machine, but when i upload the files to the server the changes are not happening. what could be the problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192314/discussion-on-question-by-zubair-shah-fav-icon-and-style-not-appearing-on-live-w).

Comment: The code you provided should work but it is not deployed on https://competebig.com/

Comment: I would never use a Backslash and an empty space in my filenames in the web